# Generalization of Power Series

Tags: approximation-theory

Given a smooth function $f(x):$

Does there always exist an expansion of x around a point $x_{0}$ of the form $$\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{h(f^{(n)}(x_{0}))}{n!}g(x-x0,n)$$ for some functions $h(c),g(a,b)$?

As an example, analytic functions have $g(A,n) = A^n$ and $h(y) =y$

Answer (score 0):

No. Let $f(x):=e^{-1/x^2}$ if $x \ne 0$ and $f(0):=0$.

It is well-known that, with $x_0=0$, $f^{(n)}(0)=0$ for $n=0,1,2,...$.

Hence, whatever $g(x-x_0,n)$ is, we have

$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}{f^{(n)}(x_0)/n!*g(x-x0,n)}=0 \ne f(x)$ for $x \ne 0$.

Comment: I forgot a part does it still hold now?

Comment: @MalachiWadas I think still no - in fact, I think your general idea of what you're looking for doesn't always hold. The function specified up there ($f(x)=e^{-1/x^2}$) is what's called a flat function at x=0. This means that all of its derivatives vanish at x=0. Consider reading about flat functions on Wikipedia - I believe it's right up the alley of what you're looking for.